# Query é executada, mas os dados não vão para o banco

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, query

Boa tarde, Galera, tô estudando o PDO e to com a seguinte dificuldade, a query executa (Ou melhor, não me retorna nenhum erro), só que quando eu vou no banco não tem nada, o que eu faço?

```
 pdo = new PDO ("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=clientes;","root","");
       } catch (PDOException $erro){
           echo "Não Foi possivel conectar ao Banco: ".$erro->getMessage();
       }


   }
   public function cadastrar($nome, $email, $cpf, $data_nascimento, $telefone, $endereco, $data_do_cadastro){

              //Checa se já há algum CPF igual no banco
              $checa_cpf =  $this-> pdo -> prepare ("select CPF from cliente where CPF = :cpf");
              $checa_cpf -> bindParam (':cpf', $cpf);
              $checa_cpf -> execute();

               if ($checa_cpf -> rowCount() >= 1){
                   echo "Cadastro já existente.";
               } else {
                try{

                   $insert = $this-> pdo ->prepare("INSERT INTO clientes(nome, cpf, email, data_nascimento, telefone, endereco, data_do_cadastro )
                   values (':nome',':cpf' ,':email',':data_nascimento', ':telefone',':endereco', ':data_do_cadastro')");
                   $insert -> bindParam(':nome', $nome);
                   $insert -> bindParam (':cpf', $cpf);
                   $insert -> bindParam (':email', $email);
                   $insert -> bindParam (':data_nascimento', $data_nascimento);
                   $insert -> bindParam (':telefone', $telefone);
                   $insert -> bindParam (':endereco', $endereco);
                   $insert -> bindParam (':data_do_cadastro', $data_do_cadastro = date ('d-m-Y'));
                   $insert -> execute();


              }catch (PDOException $erro){
                      echo "Não foi possivel inserir os dados no banco: ".$erro->getMessage();
              }

        }


   }

   public function apagarCadastro($cpf){
           //Executa uma query que apaga os dados o banco
    try{
           $stmt = $this-> pdo -> prepare("DELETE FROM CLIENTE WHERE CPF = ':cpf' ");
           $stmt-> bindParam (':cpf', $cpf);
           $stmt -> execute();
    }
    catch (PDOException $erro) {
           echo "Não foi possivel apagar os dados: ". $erro->getMessage();
    }
    if ($this -> pdo -> rowcount() >=1 ){
           echo "Todos os dados foram apagados com Sucesso.";
       }
   }
   public function atualizarNome($newNome, $oldNome){
           //Executa uma query que atualiza o nome no banco
           try {
           $this -> pdo -> prepare ("UPDATE CLIENTES SET NOME = ':nome' WHERE NOME = ':nome2'");
           $this -> pdo -> bindParam (':nome', $newNome);
           $this -> pdo -> bindParam (':nome2', $oldNome);
           } catch (PDOException $erro){
               echo "Não foi possível atualizar os dados". $erro->getMessage();
           }
   }
   public function atualizarEmail(){
       //Executa uma query que atualiza o banco
   }
   public function atualizarSenha(){
       //Executa uma query que atualiza o banco
   }
   public function exibeDados(){
       //Executa uma query que da um select no banco

   }
   public function getPdo() {



   }

}
```

Comment: Não uso PDO, mas não será para ser `:nome` ao invés de `':nome'`, removendo o `'`, assim como nos outros valores de `':cpf'` que seria `:cpf`...

Comment: @inkeliz Nem é, cara, eu tentei trocar e nada, pior que ele executa o echo de cadastrado com sucesso, mas não insere os dados no banco, to morrendo aqui já uahsuahsuha uma semana p inserir dados em um banco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opa, um dos erros que vi no seu código é que esta tratando no inicio do código  o pdo como constante sendo que não é

```
    pdo = new PDO ("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=clientes;","root","");
   } catch (PDOException $erro){
       echo "Não Foi possivel conectar ao Banco: ".$erro->getMessage();
   }
   }
```

o correto seria $pdo, indo mais além no seu código vi que está usando o metódo $this->pdo

o correto seria utilziar uma classe construtora, esta é classe que eu uso para meus projetos

```
<?php


define('HOST', '');
define('DBNAME', ''); 
define('CHARSET', 'utf8');
define('USER', '');
define('PASSWORD', '');

class Conexao {

private static $pdo;


private function __construct() {

}

public static function getInstance() {
    if (!isset(self::$pdo)) {
        try {
            $opcoes = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES UTF8',  array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
            self::$pdo = new \PDO("mysql:host=" . HOST . "; dbname=" . DBNAME . "; charset=" . CHARSET . ";", USER, PASSWORD);
            self::$pdo->setAttribute( \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            print "Erro: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
    return self::$pdo;
}
}
```

para utilizar a classe basta incluir o arquivo no seu php na classe crud exemplo

```
<?php require_once('Conexao.php');  
class SuaClasse{
public function __construct(){
$this->pdo = Conexao::getInstance();
}
public function Inserir($args){
$stmt =  $this->pdo->prepare('');
}
}
?>
```